# Draw line from point based on the angle between the 3 points

Tags: c++, math, vector, 2d, angle

How can I draw a line starting from one point in the direction of the angle between the points? [image]

This is what I have for calculating the angle

```
double angle1 = atan2(point_1_y - point_2_y, point_3_x - point_2_x);
double angle2 = atan2(point_1_y - point_3_y, point_3_x - point_2_x);
double result = angle1 - angle2;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are given three points; what do you wish to calculate?

Comment: @Beta Thanks. I want to get the direction starting from point A going down the middle based on the angle of point B and C, like what's shown in the photo.

Comment: Yes use vector logic. Construct two vectors going out of point A, average them and you have the direction of your line.

Comment: Did you try to search something like "calculate angle bisector"? You can even add c++ keyword if you like.

Comment: By *direction,* do you mean the angle, or a vector? Or a normalised vector?

Comment: @Beta The angle since the average of two vectors seems to be inaccurate for parallel shapes.

Answer (score 0):

First write a function to normalise a vector:

```
double mag = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
x = x/mag;
y = y/mag;
```

(I don't know what language you use, so I don't know the syntax of a function.)

Then apply it to the two vectors:

```
double x1 = point_C_x - point_A_x;
double y1 = point_C_y - point_A_y;
normalise(x1, y1);

double x2 = point_B_x - point_A_x;
double y2 = point_B_y - point_A_y;
normalise(x2, y2);
```

Then add them to get a green vector, then use atan2:

```
double x_green = x1+x2;
double y_green = y1+y2;
double d = atan2(y_green, x_green);
```